# Show that the two maps are equivalent

Tags: group-theory

> Question:
>   Let G be a group and let $g \in G$. If $z \in Z\left ( G \right )$, show that the inner automorphism induced by g is the same as the inner automorphism induced by $zg$.
>   That is show that, $\phi_{g}=\phi_{zg}$

Note that $Z\left ( G \right )=\left \{ z \in G \mid zg=gz \forall g \in G \right \}$

Define 
$\phi_{g}:G\rightarrow G$
$x \mapsto \left ( x \right )\phi_{g}=gxg^{-1}$

Define 
$\phi_{zg}:G\rightarrow G$
$x \mapsto \left ( x \right )\phi=zgx\left ( zg \right )^{-1}=zgxg^{-1}z^{-1}$

$\left ( x \right )\phi_{zg}=zgxg^{-1}z^{-1} but z \in Z\left ( G \right ) $so
$\left ( g^{-1}zg \right )gxg^{-1}z^{-1}=zgxg^{-1}z^{-1}$

I am unable to progress further.

Hint is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the fact that $z\in Z(G)$?

Comment: Yes I have. if z is in Z(G), the zg=gz for all g in G.

Comment: I have edited the main post to include the additional information in my attempt.

Comment: $Z(G)$ is the kernel of that homomorphism from $G$ to $\operatorname{Aut(G)}$ that maps each element of $g \in G$ to its induced inner automorphism $\phi_g$. The result is an immediate consequence.

Answer (score 1):

$zgxg^{-1}z^{-1}=gzxz^{-1}g^{-1}=gzz^{-1}xg^{-1}=gxg^{-1}$
because $z^{-1}\in Z(G)$

Answer (score 1):

For each $g \in G$, let $\phi_g$ denote the inner automorphism induced by $g$. Then we know that<sup>[1]</sup> the map $\gamma: G \to \operatorname{Aut} G$ is a homomorphism with kernel $\ker \gamma = Z(G)$. We also know that for any homomorphism $\sigma$ from a group $G$, $\sigma(g) = \sigma(gk)$ for all $k \in \ker \varphi$. Thus, $\phi_g = \gamma(g) = \gamma(gz) = \phi_{gz}$ for all $z \in Z(G)$.

---

<sup>1</sup>For any $g, x \in G$, $\phi_g(x) = x \iff gxg^{-1} = x$, that is, $x$ commutes with $g$. Now, $\ker \gamma$ consists of all elements $z$ of $G$ that fix every element $x \in G$ (and thus acts as the trivial automorphism), which is exactly the set of all elements $z$ that commute with every element of $G$, so that $\ker \gamma = Z(G)$.

Answer (score 0):

let $z\in Z(G)$ and $g\in G$, $\phi_g=\phi_{zg}\Leftrightarrow gxg^{-1}=zgx(zg)^{-1}\forall x\in G$ 
so to show $\phi_g=\phi_{zg}$ is  equivalently to show
that: $e= zgx(zg)^{-1}gx^{-1}g^{-1}\forall x\in G$ where $e$ is the
identity of $G$.

as $zy=yz\forall y\in G$ and
$(yt)^{-1}=t^{-1}y^{-1}\forall y,t\in G$ we have:
$zgx(zg)^{-1}gx^{-1}g^{-1}=gxzg^{-1}z^{-1}gx^{-1}g^{-1}=gxg^{-1}zz^{-1}gx^{-1}g^{-1}=gxg^{-1}gx^{-1}g^{-1}=gxx^{-1}g^{-1}=gg^{-1}=e\forall
x\in G$

Comment: I propose  you my answer just to understand your block